# LINQ - C# - Using lambda - Get a set of data from a Collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a struct TimePoint which is similar to a Point except, the x value is a datetime, an observable collection of these timepoints and a method that takes a datetime and returns a double value.

I want to retrieve the max and min value of the doubles that are returned from the datetimes
in this collection.

I am new to linq and am unable to figure out the query I would have to pass on the observable collection to achieve this.

Here's what I am trying to get:

```
double minDouble = 0;
double maxDouble = 0;

foreach(TimePoint item in obsColl)
{
    var doubleVal = ConvertToDouble(item.X); //Here x is a datetime
    if(minDouble > doubleVal)
        minDouble = doubleVal;
    if(maxDouble < doubleVal)
        maxDouble = doubleVal;
}
```

How can I achieve this using LINQ? Or is LINQ not ideal for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Max` and `Min` for this:

```
double minDouble = obsColl.Min(item => ConvertToDouble(item.X));
double maxDouble = obsColl.Max(item => ConvertToDouble(item.X));
```

Comment: Would this cause an internal iteration on the entire collection? What I mean is if I run the Min once and the max once, is it an O(n) performance twice?

Comment: @Harsha yes, that's my understanding -- it will iterate over the whole collection (although for all I know there may be some kind of optimization built in).  The Linq methods like `Max` and `Min` are extension methods of `IEnumerable`, so at their core you can assume they're simply performing an iteration.

Answer (score 3):

you can go over this examples [101 LINQ Samples](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.msdn.microsoft.com%2F101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b&ei=S6KkUKLHErDD0AWQhICQCA&usg=AFQjCNE8mRSbV9y7YZ-Uhiwvtx-rS4CP5A)

Comment: +1 Finally, someone else who wants the people to help themselves with the right material. :o)

Answer (score 2):

It is more efficient

```
    double minDouble =ConvertToDouble( obsColl.Min(item => item.X));
    double maxDouble = ConvertToDouble(obsColl.Max(item => item.X));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the fluent assertion package

```
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var list = new List<double>() { 1, 3, 5, 2, 9, 4 };

        var minmax = from l in list
                     group l by 1 into g
                     select new
                     {
                         min = g.Min(),
                         max = g.Max()
                     };

        minmax.First().min.Should().Be(1);
        minmax.First().max.Should().Be(9);
    }
```

Now the **group l by 1 into g** is a hack because linq will not
allow aggregates without groups but it is not too bad

Comment: That being said the internal algorithm probably uses two loops where in your foreach you can manage just one. If performance is an issue for you profile the two solutions and pick the better one.